Using Webpack Module Federation with "react": "^18.3.1", host and client face ScriptExternalLoadError:
While loading the host application I'm facing issue with the webpack module federation with the error  "Initialization of sharing external failed: ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.".
Here is my web pack configuration.
Host
//host-app/webpack.config.js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const { dependencies } = require("./package.json");
 
module.exports = {
 entry: "./src/index",
 mode: "development",
 optimization: {
    // runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: module => (module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/) || [])[1]
        }
      }
    }
  },
 devServer: {
   port: 3000, 
   open: true,
   hot: true,
   historyApiFallback: true,
   headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: "babel-loader",
           options: {
             presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
           },
         },
       ],
     },
     {
       test: /\.css$/i,
       use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
     },
   ],
 },
 plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: "./public/index.html",
     favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
     manifest: "./public/manifest.json",
   }),
   new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "Remote CoreShell Client",
    remotes: {
      // TODO replace the url with base url 
      Remote: `Remote@http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js`,
    },  
    shared: {
      ...dependencies,
      react: {
        singleton: true,
        eager: true,
        requiredVersion: dependencies["react"],
      },
      "react-dom": {
        singleton: true,
        eager: true,
        requiredVersion: dependencies["react-dom"],
      },
    },
  }),
 ],
 resolve: {
   extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
 },
 target: "web",
}

Remote
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const { dependencies } = require("./package.json");
 
module.exports = {
 entry: "./src/index.js",
 mode: "production",
 devServer: {
   static: {
     directory: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
   },
   port: 3001,
   historyApiFallback: true,
  //  watchFiles: ["src/**/*"],
   client: {
    webSocketURL: 'ws://localhost:3000/ws',
  },
 },
 output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:3001/'
},
optimization: {
  minimize: true,
  minimizer: [
    new TerserPlugin({
      terserOptions: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true, // Optional: Drop console statements
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendor', // Fixed name for the vendor bundle
              chunks: 'all',
          },
      },
  }
},
module: {
  rules: [
      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                }
          }
      }, {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },{
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json-loader', // Add this rule for JSON files
          type: 'javascript/auto',
      },
      {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [
              'file-loader'
          ]
      },
      {
          test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
          use: [
              'file-loader'
          ]
      }
  ]
},
 plugins: [
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
     publicPath: "http://localhost:3001/", // Add this to resolve PUBLIC_URL issues
     inject: true,
   }),
   new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: "Remote",
    filename: "moduleEntry.js",
    exposes: {
      "./Dashboard": "./src/App",
    },
    shared: {
      ...dependencies,
      react: {
        singleton: true,
        requiredVersion: dependencies["react"],
        eager: true
      },
      "react-dom": {
        singleton: true,
        requiredVersion: dependencies["react-dom"],
        eager: true
      },
    },
  }),
 ],
 resolve: {
   extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
 },
 target: "web",
};

The dependencies versions that I'm using for this application are .
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"webpack": "^5.96.1"
I can see the module http://localhost:3001/moduleEntry.js loading in the remote app but having this issue.
Initialization of sharing external failed: ScriptExternalLoadError: Loading script failed.
